# The problem with the command: titleformat it is important

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

This is my first post here.

I am using a few commands and packages to make the titles behave according to my thesis specifications but when I used the `\titleformat`  I get an error:

```
! Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode.

See the titlesec package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.24 \section{THE ZEROS OF $\zeta(s)$}
```

How can I solve this?
This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}[section]
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\titleformat{\section}{\textsc}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
...
\begin{center}
\section{THE ZEROS OF $\zeta(s)$}
\end{center}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: I did not know that this is possible. I'll remember that. Can you help me with this \titleformat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\titleformat` takes more arguments, you are using the syntax of `\titleformat*`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}[section]
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\titleformat*{\section}{\scshape\centering}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
...

\section{THE ZEROS OF $\zeta(s)$}

\setcounter{equation}{0}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Still does not look like the first picture. The letter T must be higher than the others and is equal with them.

Comment: @Kasia That is Caps and Small caps: if _you_ enter the title as `THE` then it will come out as THE in sc shape, If you enter it as `The` then the lowercase letters are small caps. Your question does not mention you wanted to change the text, only that you had an error in your use of the titesec commands.

Comment: I'm sorry I wrote a big letter I wrote a small font that works.

Comment: @Kasia no need to be sorry, no harm done:-)

Comment: I have written in my language. Already working as I wanted, there is no error. Thank you very much. I still have one question. I will not write a new post. Here is a question. How do I change the number of equations were left not right?

Comment: @Kasia use `[leqno]` option to the `\documentclass`

Comment: Now for me it negates some of the paragraphs of the text to the left. I can do that indentation (paragraphs) than pressing enter?

Comment: sorry I don't understand. Perhaps you should make a code example and a new question (The system is getting cross with us for the length of this comment thread)

Comment: I again wrote to the Polish ... It's not that important. Just the question is whether it is correct if I use Entera to do a paragraph.

Comment: @Kasia a blank line is a paragraph break in tex yes (so two enter/return)

Answer (score 2):

An example of the working one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}[section]
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\titleformat{\section}{}{}{0pt}{\textsc}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}


...
%\begin{center}
\section{The zeros $\zeta(s)$}
%\end{center}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
...
\end{document}
```

The fourth parameter must be a length.